# Why PyQt6 won't properly update paintGL after adding updated array through glBufferSubData?

Tags: python, opengl, pyqt, qt6, pyqt6

When I press left or right key to rotate 4 points around origin, the screen won't update correctly causing broken rendering. The vertex array is properly introduced to buffer, but I have not found relevant information regarding why this won't render properly.
[image: Broken render]
Here are the relevant codes:

```
import Shader
from Math_3d import Vector3f
from OpenGL.GL import *
from PyQt6.QtOpenGLWidgets import QOpenGLWidget
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt


class GLWidget(QOpenGLWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Vertex Buffer Object
        # Create point vertex data
        self.v3f = Vector3f([[0.5, 0.5, 0.0],
                            [-0.5, -0.5, 0.0],
                            [0.5, -0.5, 0.0],
                            [-0.5, 0.5, 0.0]])
        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.FocusPolicy.StrongFocus)

    def initializeGL(self):
               program = glCreateProgram()
        buffer = glGenBuffers(1)
        # Request program and shader slots from the GPU
        vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)

        # Set shader sources
        glShaderSource(vertex, Shader.vertex_code)
        glShaderSource(fragment, Shader.fragment_code)
        # Compile shaders and check that they have compiled
        glCompileShader(vertex)
        glCompileShader(fragment)
        if not glGetShaderiv(vertex, GL_COMPILE_STATUS):
            report_shader = glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex)
            print(report_shader)
            raise RuntimeError("Vertex shader compilation error")

        if not glGetShaderiv(fragment, GL_COMPILE_STATUS):
            report_frag = glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment)
            print(report_frag)
            raise RuntimeError("Fragment shader compilation error")

        # Link shaders to program
        glAttachShader(program, vertex)
        glAttachShader(program, fragment)
        glLinkProgram(program)

        if not glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS):
            print(glGetProgramInfoLog(program))
            raise RuntimeError('Linking error')
        # Get rid of shaders
        glDetachShader(program, vertex)
        glDetachShader(program, fragment)
        # Make default program to run
        glUseProgram(program)

        # Make this buffer the default one
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer)
        # Vertex Array Buffer
        vao = glGenVertexArrays(1)
        glBindVertexArray(vao)
        strides = int(self.v3f.buffdata.nbytes/self.v3f.buffdata.itemsize)
        loc = glGetAttribLocation(program, 'position')
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc)
        glVertexAttribPointer(loc, 3, GL_FLOAT, False, strides, None)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.v3f.buffdata.nbytes, self.v3f.buffdata, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW)

   def paintGL(self):
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        glPointSize(20)
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, self.v3f.buffdata.itemsize)

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key() == Qt.Key.Key_Left:
            self.v3f.Rotate(-0.1)
            print("Left")
        elif e.key() == Qt.Key.Key_Right:
            self.v3f.Rotate(0.1)
            print("Right")
        elif e.key() == Qt.Key.Key_Escape or Qt.Key.Key_Q:
            exit()
        self.update()
```

Other module:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(precision=3, suppress=True)


class Vector3f:
    def __init__(self, ndarray):
        self.data = np.array([ndarray], dtype=np.float32)
        # Convert n-dimension arrays to one long array
        self.buffdata = self.data.ravel()
        self.orig = self.data
        self.__rval = 0.0
        self.__sval = 0.0

    def Rotate(self, val):  # Rotation Matrix
        self.__rval += val  # Create a memory value and add to that value
        m1 = np.asmatrix(self.data)  # Convert n-dimension array to matrix
        rot2 = np.matrix([[np.cos(self.__rval), np.sin(-self.__rval), 0.0],  # Create rotation matrix
                         [np.sin(self.__rval), np.cos(self.__rval), 0.0],
                         [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]], dtype=np.float32)
        rotator = m1 * rot2  # Matrix multiplication
        self.buffdata = rotator.ravel()  # Convert result to array to be used on GPU buffer
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, self.buffdata.data.nbytes, self.buffdata.data)
```

Comment: `glBufferSubData` can only update the data store of an buffer, after the data store was created  with `glBufferData`. `glBufferSubData` can only change data, but not the size of a data store.

Comment: In this case the size of data store stays the same, but data is updated.

Comment: You need to check for errors using [`glGetError`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetError.xhtml).  Apart from anything else, I suspect there is no valid current OpenGL context when `keyPressEvent` (and hence `Vector3f.Rotate`) is called.

Comment: Added OpenGL initialization to give better comparison for the problem.

Comment: Why do you transform all vertices in the buffer instead of transforming them in the vertex shader?

Comment: Is `buffer` still bound when `glBufferSubData` is called?

Comment: Is the OpenGL context even the current context in the `keyPressEvent` callback? As far as I know the OpenGL context is only activated in `initializeGL`  and `paintGL` (in the *GL) methods.

Comment: For the previous three questions. Vertices will be modified during runtime using pymesh. buffer is still bound when calling glBufferSubData. In the keyPressEvent callback the OpenGL context should be correct as it calls the instance data modification in store.

Comment: Re. `"the OpenGL context should be correct as it calls the instance data modification in store"`: sorry, but I have no idea what that's supposed to mean. There's no reason to assume the context has been correctly set anywhere outside of the `initializeGL`, `paintGL` or `resizeGL` members (as far as I recall). Add a call to `glGetError` immediately after `self.update()` call in `keyPressEvent` and check the value it returns.

Answer (score 1):

For any OpenGL instruction a current and valid [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) is required. [`QOpenGLWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qopenglwidget.html) creates an OpenGL context, but the context is only made current before the `initializeGL`, `paintGL`, or `resizeGL` callback.
Therefore you cannot use OpenGL instructions outside the scope of these functions and this is the reason why the call to `glBufferSubData` fails when called through `keyPressEvent`.